# OOZIE - Create a coordinator app on unknown file name

Tags: bigdata, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I want to make a coordinator app on a list of files but i only know their name parttern:
/data/trigger/projet/*

I want to resolve the following HDFS URL:

```
/data/trigger/projet/ffff_2013-01-01
/data/trigger/projet/aaaa_2013-01-02
/data/trigger/projet/bbbb_2013-01-03
```

When i try the following code, oozie doesn't detect anything and stay on WAITING state:

```
<datasets>
<dataset name="DataSet" frequency="${frequency}" initial-instance="${startTime}" timezone="${timezone}">
<uri-template>/data/trigger/projet/*</uri-template>
</dataset>
</datasets>


<input-events>
<data-in name="InputEvent" dataset="DataSet">
<instance>${startTime}</instance>
</data-in>
</input-events>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use * in the URI template in oozie